# Testing for CSS Selenium locators from the browser

Tags: selenium

In general, when I want to test the validity of a locator to be used in Selenium, I test it using the Firebug console.

i.e., I write: `$$("a#someLink")` in the Firebug console and the corresponding link becomes highlighted in Firefox.

However, if I test in Firebug for a locator like:
`table#someTable tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(2)`
Firebug doesn't show anything... Even though the locator works fine from Selenium...
I guess Selenium uses some 'hacks' for CSS locators, which Firebug does not understand...

Is there any way around it? Would using Xpath locators allow me to test for those kinds of locators?

Thank you very much

Comment: What Firefox/Firebug/Selenium do you use?

I use Firefox 5 and Firebug 1.8.0 and your selector works.

Here is my HTML
`<html>
 <head>
  <title>111</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table id="someTable">
   <tr>

    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>

    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>

  </table>
 </body>
</html>`

And your selector returns me valid <td> element.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I'm using Firefox 4 and Firebug 1.8.0... I ended up using Xpath locators and there was no problem with selenium (and firebug)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug has an extension called FireFinder, which allows you to test xpath or css locators and it shows all the matches on the page. Here's [a link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/).